# how to create Firewall Rules with API in Azure?

Tags: azure, api, post, ip, firewall

I need to create Firewall Rules in a database in Azure, to allow certain ips to access, I found that documentation but I do not know exactly what steps to do.

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/rest/api/sql/firewallrules/createorupdate

I already know how to consume a service using GET, PUT, POST, or DELETE. but for more that I send the POST it returns this to me.

[image]

I think I need to send the credentials, before sending the POST

How to do this? the other question is that I do not want to do it directly from the portal, because I need a program that I am developing to do it through the consumption of the API

Answer (score 0):

you need to use your subscription id, not your subscription name:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{serverName}/firewallRules/{firewallRuleName}?api-version=2014-04-01
                            ^ put resourceId here
```

easiest way to retrieve that - go to that portal to the sql server in question and look up the url. it will be the exact same url (except for the first part). here's url from the portal for kv resource:

```
https://portal.azure.com/resource/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/infrastructure/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/yyy/overview
                                 ^ this is where the resourceId starts
```